# She is as intelligent as I or as I'm

Tags: sentence-construction, contractions

Let's look at the following sentences.

**He is better than I'm**.(Than is used as Conjunction)

=>*He is better than I*.

=>*He is better than me*.(Than is used as preposition).

We've dropped '*am* ' from the first sentence and made the second sentence. As far as I know they all are grammatical and mean the same thing. If I'm wrong please correct me.

Now my question is can I drop 'am' by the same way in the case of 'as'. Would this transformation be correct?

**She is as inteligent as I'm.**

=>*She is as intelligent as I*.

=>*She is as intelligent as me*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it uncommon to end a sentence with a contraction?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/is-it-uncommon-to-end-a-sentence-with-a-contraction)

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot use **I'm** at the end of a clause.  It has to be

> He's better than I am.

or

> She's as intelligent as I am.

[The general rule is "We don’t use affirmative contractions at the end of clauses."](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/contractions)  You can say "I'm short but he **isn't**", but you can't use **I'm** like that.

Comment: Ok I got to your point. Actually my question was not about contraction at the end. My question is if we can drop 'am' from the sentences 'He is better than I am ' , 'She is as intelligent as I am ' and rewrite them as 'He is better than I' and 'She is as intelligent as I'.

Comment: Yes, you can (though some posters on this forum might claim that it sounds stiff and old-fashioned!). Many casual speakers would say '...as me', though that is, strictly speaking, incorrect (because you can't say 'as me am').